# ORA-01722:invalid number - Compare 2 column values where one column has numbers and another has non-numeric values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

We have a table with two columns but due to a wrong logic the second column has the values of the first column and also non-numeric values. When trying to do a inner join to see the duplicates between columns, getting an error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number

- Table Name: Company
- Column: `id` (number)
- Column: `name` (varchar)

Possible values

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | first watch |
| 3 | {{abc_def}} |
| 4 | unknown |
| 5 | (null) |
| 6 | null |
| 7 | (whitespace)1234 |
| 8 | 456 |
| 9 | 234 567 |

Oracle query:

```
select *
from company
where id = name;
```

Results in this error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number

Expected result:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

Comment: Thank you @marc_s for fixing the table, was struggling to create it. Now i know

Answer (score 3):

It is a design error to store numbers in a VARCHAR2 column. Always use the appropriate type in order to avoid such issues.

If you must convert strings to numbers, but the strings can contain non numeric values, use `TO_NUMBER` to make the conversion explicit and use the `DEFAULT ON CONVERSION ERROR` clause to handle faulty values.

```
select *
from company 
where id = to_number(name default null on conversion error);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, got the expected result. Yes design is not right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the string to a number, or you can convert the number to a string:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   company
WHERE  TO_CHAR(id) = name;
```

Whether you can/should use `TO_CHAR` on the left-hand side of the comparison or `TO_NUMBER` on the right-hand side of the comparison depends on whether you intend to solely match cases such as `1 = '1'` or if you also intend to match `1000 = '1,000.0'`, which would have an identical numerical value but would not match as a string unless the formatting was identical.